# Is there no way to get a view that shows the latest questions, but only the title?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, homepage

With the new algorithm for the homepage view, it doesn't appear possible to toggle into a view that shows only the important information for the latest questions asked. I don't want a view like the Questions view that is so cluttered - I don't care about a preview of the body or the Gravatar of the last person to post, I just want to see the title, tags, votes, and responses.

Given the response that shows this page still exists, it could be a bug that there's no tab to display this view. If it's intentional, I would like to request that such a tab be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tab already exists, but we have no intention of showing it in the UI.

https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=active

Your workaround is to use that URL, which will be supported forever.

The reason we don't want to show this tab in the UI any more is because the Active tab no longer makes sense at Stack Overflow's level of volume/traffic. We can only display ~100 entries on the homepage and there are far more than 100 active (edited, new, etc) questions within the 2 minute caching interval. It depends on time of day, etc, but it's quite common now.

If you need this functionality, use /questions -- and if you feel the view is cluttered, try a user script that turns off some of the display.

Comment: It makes sense to not have it as a default view because of the volume, but the way I use Stack Overflow doesn't work with any other view. I come to see what people are asking about right now, without any concern for what I consider interesting (other than having them highlighted), what I have previously asked (I learn new things all the time, so I can answer new questions today that I couldn't yesterday), and score of the question, views, or number of answers (I want to see the latest and greatest questions and answers, not those that are ranked the best).

Comment: For the purposes of asking/answering questions, the Interesting view is the way to go and I like it- it does a great job of picking out questions. But for people who use Stack Overflow to learn and just read random questions, it makes it much, much more difficult. Not to mention the fact that the algorithm depends heavily on people using favorite tags (I'm going to delete mine to remove them from the algorithm), tagging properly, and people coming to answer questions instead of random reading of questions. It's just become much harder to learn from Stack Overflow without asking questions.

Comment: @thomas I suggest the hot, weekly, and monthly tabs if that's what you're into.

Comment: I'll check those out, but I'm already missing coming to SO during a break between classes and just seeing the last n active questions. There's plenty of room in the UI for another tab, as long as people realize that it might not be accurate due to caching. Hopefully "hot" is closer to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the required view by opening https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=active.

But I am not sure if the content is the expected.

Comment: OK. How do I get there and make that my default view of the site, though?

Comment: @Thomas Owens: it is not currently possible.

Comment: @Thomas Owens: at second thought I am not sure if I really answered your question. Can you check? I am going to delete it if I didn't.

Comment: It looks like it did. I would have to watch it for a while, but it looks like it does show the most recently modified questions.

Comment: I've been watching it for about 5 minutes now and, yes, this is what I want. This used to be the behavior of the homepage, until the new algorithm for showing your interesting questions was used. When that happened, this just...died.